# Why does pandas.cut categories the first element as NaN?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to first cut and then categorize an array of numerical values with labels with np.linspace and pd.cut. My code is shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n=4 #number of edges to group 'a' to three categories.
a = np.arange(2.0,5.0,0.1)
dfa = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a'])
edges, step = np.linspace(np.floor(a.min()), np.ceil(a.max()), num = n, retstep=True)
dfa['a_label'] = pd.cut(x=dfa['a'], bins=list(edges), labels=range(n-1))
print(edges)
print(dfa.head())
```

However, I got a NaN for the first element in the array when I ran it as shown in the results below. By right, the first element 2.0 should be included in the first category. Please help me figure out what went wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
[2. 3. 4. 5.]
     a a_label
0  2.0     NaN
1  2.1     0.0
2  2.2     0.0
3  2.3     0.0
4  2.4     0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add parameter `include_lowest-True` to [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

> **include_lowest** bool, default **False**
>   Whether the first interval should be left-inclusive or not.

```
dfa['a_label'] = pd.cut(x=dfa['a'], bins=list(edges), labels=range(n-1), include_lowest=True)
print(dfa.head())
     a a_label
0  2.0       0
1  2.1       0
2  2.2       0
3  2.3       0
4  2.4       0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply! It worked! I guess I should've read more into the pd.cut function..